# Função executando assim que a página carrega

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-eventos

Com os seguintes códigos
[image: html]
[image: Java script]

**Assim que eu carrego a pagina no navegador já é exibido o resultado no console**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso é padrão do javaScript ou tem algo errado no meu código? Como resolver?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**. Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

Comment: Sobre o seu problema, note que nesse trecho de código `btn.addEventListener('click', teste() )` você esta executando a função `teste()` e passando como parâmetro o retorno dela, ou seja , null

Answer (score 3):

A função `addEventListener` espera dois parâmetros - o evento que se deseja escutar, e a função que se deve executar quando ele for disparado - o primeiro você passou corretamente, o segundo, não. Quando você faz `teste()`, você está invocando a função (chamando-a). Neste caso, o que se deseja fazer é passar a própria função ao invés.

```js
button.addEventListener('click', test)
```

Agora, estamos passando a função como argumento, e ela só será chamada quando o evento for disparado.